# Fraction of a day, of a week and of a month conversion from date in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe with times:

```
id    time
1     4/01/2019 08:00:00
2     4/02/2019 12:00:00
3     4/03/2019 18:00:00
```

And I want the fraction of a day, fraction of the week and fraction of the month. For example for the first row 08:00:00 is one third of a day, so first column should be 0.333. And it was Monday so it should be 0.047 (a complete day is 1/7 = 0.143 of a week, but since it's a third then 0.143 * 0.333 = 0.047). And it was the start of the month so it should be 0.011 (a complete day is 1/30 = 0.033 of a month, but it is only 8:am so it is 0.033 * 0.333 = 0.011.

Please note that the values are for complete days, for example for 4/02/2019 12:00:00, only 1 day and a half is counted.

The expected result should be:

```
id    time                 frac_day    frac_week    frac_month
1     4/01/2019 08:00:00   0.333       0.047        0.011
2     4/02/2019 12:00:00   0.5         0.214        0.050
3     4/03/2019 18:00:00   0.75        0.393        0.092
```

Please, could you help me with this question in python? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: So using gmtime you can get the date parts, which in turn can get you the number of seconds of the day, week and month. For day and week it’s then just division by 86400 and 7*86400 seconds. For the month, you need to figure how many days are in that particular month (remember leap years) so use eg http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange to tell you this given the year and month. Finally seconds in month can be divided by month days *86400

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd, Day

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'time': ['4/01/2019 08:00:00', '4/02/2019 12:00:00',
             '4/03/2019 18:00:00']
})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# Percentage of Day by dividing current hour by number of hours in day
df['frac_day'] = df['time'].dt.hour / 24

# Get midnight the beginning of the week for each row
beginning_of_each_week = (
        df['time'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].dt.dayofweek, unit='D')
).dt.normalize()
seconds_in_week = 24 * 7 * 60 * 60

# % of week so far. by dividing total seconds by total seconds in week
df['frac_week'] = (
                          df['time'] - beginning_of_each_week
                  ).dt.total_seconds() / seconds_in_week

# Get Timedelta based on midnight of the first day of the current month
time_so_far = df['time'] - (df['time'] - MonthEnd(1) + Day(1)).dt.normalize()
# Get Total time for the given month
time_in_month = (df['time'] + MonthEnd(1)) - (df['time'] - MonthEnd(1))

# % of month so far by dividing values
df['frac_month'] = time_so_far / time_in_month
```

`df`:

```
   id                time  frac_day  frac_week  frac_month
0   1 2019-04-01 08:00:00  0.333333   0.047619    0.011111
1   2 2019-04-02 12:00:00  0.500000   0.214286    0.050000
2   3 2019-04-03 18:00:00  0.750000   0.392857    0.091667
```

Comment: Now I understand your answer @Henry Ecker, it was due to how the week starts, if Sunday or Monday, wasn't it? Thank you very much for your time and answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```py
df["frac_day"] = (
    df["time"].dt.hour * 60 * 60
    + df["time"].dt.minute * 60
    + df["time"].dt.second
) / (24 * 60 * 60)

df["frac_week"] = (df["time"].dt.dayofweek + df["frac_day"]) / 7
df["frac_month"] = df["time"].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(str(x)).days_in_month)
df["frac_month"] = ((df["time"].dt.day - 1) / df["frac_month"]) + df[
    "frac_day"
] / df["frac_month"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id                time  frac_day  frac_week  frac_month
0   1 2019-04-01 08:00:00  0.333333   0.047619    0.011111
1   2 2019-04-02 12:00:00  0.500000   0.214286    0.050000
2   3 2019-04-03 18:00:00  0.750000   0.392857    0.091667
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a lot of [built in support for time and datetime functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html).

Firstly make sure your `df['time']` column is correctly stored as a datetime and then the following should do the trick:

```py
# get number of seconds elapsed in the day - total seconds in a day
# note here we create a timedelta
# hack: use df['time'].dt.date to set time to 00:00:00
df['frac_day'] = (df['time'] - pd.to_datetime(df['time'].dt.date)).dt.total_seconds() / (24 * 3600)

df['frac_week'] = (df['time'].dt.dayofweek + df['frac_day']) / 7

df['frac_month'] = (df['time'].dt.day + df['frac_day'] - 1)/ df['time'].dt.days_in_month 

df
```

Comment: This does not produce correct values for `frac_week` or `frac_month`. Neither `frac_week` nor `frac_month` take into account the current hour in `df['time']`.

Comment: @HenryEcker you were correct, I have updated to use onliners and datetime in built functions

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. Great work @Matt

Comment: Thank you @Matt, it's a compact answer, just three lines, completely understandable!